# Plotting a Graph - Passing 1 or several files as filter

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, combobox

What do I have working:

- Reading and plotting information from a List;

What do I need:

- Before plotting, checking a ComboBox: If "All files" - Plot
  (working!); If <> than "All files", get the text from the ComboBox
  and Plot the graph with that specific file name information;

How to link ComboBox and List - In the list I have one column (named: File_Name) that will match the ComboBox.

My Code:

```
    DataForProject = CreatesListInfoForGraphPoints();
    _gData = new List<FormA_DataType.GraphData>();

    if (CboxReceiveNameFile.Text == "All files") 
    {
        foreach (GetInfoForGraph item in DataForProject)
         {
            FormA_DataType.GraphData newData = new FormA_DataType.GraphData();
            newData.Date = item.Time;
            newData.Temp1 = item.Start_inlet_temp;
            newData.Temp2 = item.Start_outlet_temp;
            newData.Type = "";
            _gData.Add(newData);
         }
    Graph.Graph(_gData);
    }
    else // If a specific file name is selected
    { // I need help here!!!
        foreach (GetInfoForGraph item in DataForProject)
        {
            FormA_DataType.GraphData newData = new FormA_DataType.GraphData();
            newData.Date = item.Time;
            newData.Temp1 = item.Start_inlet_temp;
            newData.Temp2 = item.Start_outlet_temp;
            newData.Type = "";
            _gData.Add(newData);
        }
        Graph.Graph(_gData);
    }


    Graph.Visible = true;
```

I was thinking about creating a new list with only the information (filtered by a specific file name) and plot this new list. Is there any better way of doing this? Maybe direct filter in the foreach part:

```
else // If a specific file name is selected

    { // I need help here!!!
        foreach (GetInfoForGraph item in DataForProject)
```

Some extra code:

How my ComboBox is populated with information:

```
private void CboxReceiveNameFile_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CboxReceiveNameFile.Items.Clear();

    foreach (GetInfoForGraph item in DataForProject)
    {
        if (!CboxReceiveNameFile.Items.Contains(item.File_Name))
        {
            CboxReceiveNameFile.Items.Add(item.File_Name.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```

- How I do create the information for the list:

  ```
      try
      {
          conn.Open();
          dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (dr.Read())
          {
              DataForGraph.Add(new GetInfoForGraph()
              {
                  Start_inlet_temp = dr.GetFloat(dr.GetOrdinal("Start_inlet_temp")),
                  Start_outlet_temp = dr.GetFloat(dr.GetOrdinal("Start_outlet_temp")),
                  Time = dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("Time")),
                  Customer_name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Customer_name")),
                  Program_name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Program_name")),
                  Type_name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Type_name")),
                  Id_Tbl_Program = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id_Tbl_Program")),
                  Id_Tbl_File_Names = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id_Tbl_File_Names")),
                  File_Name = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("File_Name"))
              });

          }
          dr.Close();
  ```

  Please, let me know if I should include any extra information.
  Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem this way:

```
    else // If a specific file name is selected
    {
        //List<int> filteredfiles = DataForProject.Where(x => DataForProject.w == CboxReceiveNameFile.Text).ToList();

        foreach (GetInfoForGraph item in DataForProject.Where(list => list.File_Name == CboxReceiveNameFile.Text))
        {
            FormA_DataType.GraphData newData = new FormA_DataType.GraphData();
            newData.Date = item.Time;
            newData.Temp1 = item.Start_inlet_temp;
            newData.Temp2 = item.Start_outlet_temp;
            newData.Type = "";
            _gData.Add(newData);
        }
        Graph.Graph(_gData);
    }
```

I hope that it can help somebody!